# is there any separate lightning lead conversion class?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, lead-conversion

So i came across lightning lead conversion process that allows you to

> convert a lead to existing opportunity

and updates the OpportunityId on lead as convertedOpportunityId.

what i'm wondering about is, if we are able to do that via UI, why not with apex. I tried to **setOpportunityId in LeadConvert** class but throws an error as invalid signature method.

is this still not possible? what am i missing?

Comment: Presumably, this is probably on the roadmap, but it looks like all you get today is a UI feature. I don't see anything about a new method or class for supporting this feature.

Comment: Thank you, that’s what I thought. I wonder if someone will comment from development  team